# javax.net.ssl.sslpeerunverifiedexception:peernotauthenticated jmeter error

Tags: jmeter

Hi how to rectify below error in jmeter

javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:572)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:640)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:284)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.followRedirects(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1390)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.resultProcessing(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1461)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.resultProcessing(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:356)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1075)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1064)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:426)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:255)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Please provide more information. What sampler and config do you use? How does the server authenticate? Are certificates involved?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is a bug as documented here: [Apache bugzilla](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54759).

Here is also the changes in JMeter to  [solve of this bug](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=r1467823).

So maybe, having the latest library can solve this problem.